# Uncaught syntax error unexpected identifier JavaScript objects

Tags: javascript

When I write this code and look at the console

```
var people= {
country: {
name:"Costa Rica",
city: "San José"
}
};

console.log(country)
```

I get the following error:      app3.js:8 Uncaught ReferenceError: country is not defined  at app3.js:8

What is happening? Please, help me; I'm starting in JavaScript and this simple thing is stopping me. (The console is wrong? haha)

Comment: Nothing wrong with that code. Problem probably originates higher up.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now i have created a new .js and only left that code. Now i get:  app3.js:8 Uncaught ReferenceError: country is not defined
    at app3.js:8
(anonymous) @ app3.js:8

Comment: Could you update the code in your question? There is no line 8 in the code you've shown and it's saying the error is on line 8 (app3.js:8).

Comment: Ok, i did it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `console.log(country)` to `console.log(people.country);`.

`country` isn't defined where you call `console.log`. `country` is only defined within the `people` object.

Comment: Incredible! How i didn't realize that. Thank you !